# 'Card' may not respond to '-fadeAway'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, warnings

I have a Card class subclassed from UIView and a Deck class from NSObject.  Card has a few integer properties on top of the inherited UIView ones and Deck has an NSMutableArray for holding some cards.  After generating a deck of cards, I want to display a randomly selected card (by adding it to the superview).  Before I do, I check to see if there is a card already, I call a method to release it before asking for a new one.  But I get the warning in the title.  Here's the code...

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Card.h"
#import "Deck.h"

@interface FlashTestViewController : UIViewController {

Deck*       aDeck;
Card*       aCard;
}

- (IBAction)generateDeck;
- (IBAction)generateCard;
- (void)fadeAway:(id)sender;

@end
```

---

```
#import "FlashTestViewController.h"

@implementation FlashTestViewController

- (IBAction)generateDeck {

    if (aDeck != nil) {
        [aDeck release];
    }

    aDeck = [[Deck alloc] initDeckWithOperator:@"+"];
}


- (IBAction)generateCard {

    if (aCard != nil) {
        [aCard fadeAway];
    }

    aCard = [aDeck newCardFromDeck];
    [self.view addSubview:aCard];
}

- (void)fadeAway:(id)sender {
    [aCard removeFromSuperview];
    [aCard release];
    }
```

---

I am a beginner at programming (other than Basic!) so I'm still wrapping my head around the whole object thing.  Thanks for any help and/or advice!

EDIT:
Here's the Card and Deck code...

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@class Card;

@interface Card : UIView {

int         upperOperand;
int         lowerOperand;
NSString*   theOperator;
int         theResult;
}

@property(nonatomic) int upperOperand;
@property(nonatomic) int lowerOperand;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* theOperator;
@property(nonatomic) int theResult;

@end
```

---

```
#import "Card.h"


@implementation Card

@synthesize upperOperand;
@synthesize lowerOperand;
@synthesize theOperator;
@synthesize theResult;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
    // Initialization code
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    self.alpha = 0.3;
    self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
    self.layer.borderWidth = 4;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Card.h"

@class Deck;

@interface Deck : NSObject {

NSMutableArray* cards;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* cards;

- (id)initDeckWithOperator: (NSString*)mathOper;
- (id)newCardFromDeck;

@end
```

---

```
#import "Deck.h"

@implementation Deck

@synthesize cards;

- (id)initDeckWithOperator: (NSString*)mathOper {
    if (cards != nil) {
    [cards release];
    }
    cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<11; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<11; j++) {
            Card* aCard = [[Card alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 60, 80)];
            aCard.upperOperand = i;
            aCard.lowerOperand = j;
            aCard.theOperator = mathOper;
            aCard.theResult = i + j;
            [cards addObject: aCard];
            [aCard release];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)newCardFromDeck {
    int index = random() % [cards count];
    Card* selectedCard = [[cards objectAtIndex:index] retain];
    [cards removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    return selectedCard;
}

@end
```

Comment: Why, do you need an `(id)sender` just curious?

Comment: Not sure exactly.  My logic was that I needed to send the aCard instance to the method so that it would know what to release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've defined the `fadeAway` method for the `FlashTestViewController` class, not the `Card` class.  That means that you can only call this method (or send the message depending on your preferred OOP terminology) on instances of the `Card` class.

so `[aCard fadeAway]` is incorrect because it takes the wrong number of params, but also because aCard is a `Card` class instance and the `fadeAway:` method isn't defined for that class (well, we don't see the definition of it, so maybe it is but not visibly so).

But you didn't show the definition of the `Card` class so maybe you DO define the method there.

Comment: I don't have a fadeAway method in the Card class.  I still get confused by where different bits of functionality should go.  I thought that a method for dismissing a card should go in the controller, but maybe it should be in the Card class.  I'll post my Card and Deck code as an answer.

Comment: Actually - I'll edit the original question as the friendly web site is suggesting to me... =)

Comment: I put the fadeAway method into the Card class without a sender and - voila! it works!  When I build the deck of cards, I used random numbers to make the x and y position of the frame, and each time you tap the New Card button, the old card disappears and the new one appears somewhere else.  Now to actually make it fade, and to get the content into the UIView.

Thanks so much for the help!!!  I'd vote up the answers, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: @Steve: " *I still get confused by where different bits of functionality should go* ".  Apple pushes the model-view-controller pattern for GUI applications.  If you want to follow the approved pattern, you would separate the code to do with rendering the card on the screen e.g. fading away and the code to do with the logical abstraction of a playing card into separate classes.  You'd have a Card class (model) and a CardView class (view). -fadeAway would go in CardView.

Comment: I see - I've been trying to understand the MVC thing but it's taking time to sink in.  I never thought to split the code for the card into two parts.  I've been thinking about a "card object" and I figured that "card object" had to be MV or C, but not M and V both.  This is hard stuff, but fun.  Thanks again for the guidance - I'd have given up without it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `aCard` an `(id)sender` as you stated in your parameters. Your not giving enough arguments to put it in other words.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `fadeAway` as taking a single parameter of type `id`, so you have to call it that way. So:

```
[aCard fadeAway:nil];
```

Also, since it never does anything with its argument, you could simply declare it as not taking one, and then call it as is. So:

```
-(void)fadeAway;

// later
[aCard fadeAway];
```